# Ionic native app update not working. How can I solve this?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I'm using @ionic-native/app-update,
When the update is in progress, only the app version code is checked, and then the update does not proceed. (Progress bar does not move)

My app os android.

Below is the issue situation.

How can I solve this?

update part 1. (response : 'update check success')

[image]

update part 2. ('need update!, button: 'update')

[image]

**update part3. (version is updating...)
but update progress bar never move.....**

[image]

my update.xml file.

[image]

my update code

[image]

The appk file download works when I access the URL below from my browser.
url : http://my-update-server/2.apk

If my explanation is insufficient, please let me know.
Please give me a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

@ionic-native has changed to [@awesome-cordova-plugins](https://danielsogl.gitbook.io/awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-update-1). You need to Update your packages to reflect this change.